# How do I run more than one X display?

Tags: xorg

A distribution like Arch Linux has six virtual terminals accessible by the keyboard keys alt + F1, F2, ..., F6 by default. Running xinit starts the X display which is accessible by alt + F7.

I wish to run two X displays, one at alt + F7 and one at alt + F8. How do I do this?

I am sure I am not looking for the virtual desktop provided by the window manager. I actually want two X displays. The solution should, for example, let me run two different window managers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/inittab` you will find something like this:

```
c1:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 38400 tty1 linux
c2:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 38400 tty2 linux
c3:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 38400 tty3 linux
c4:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 38400 tty4 linux
c5:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 38400 tty5 linux
c6:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 -s 38400 tty6 linux
```

The line after that controls X., copy it, put it right after, change all `7`s to `8`. Add `-- :1` after it if there is no `:0`, or change `:0` to `:1`.

**Note:** I don't have an Arch Linux installation with me. This is the theory.

Answer (score 1):

Give a different display number to the X server – e.g. `xinit -- :1` – or use `startx`, which automatically chooses the first unused display (based on `/tmp/.X*-lock`).

The new X11 display will run on the first unallocated VT; this can be changed by adding an `vcN` argument: `xinit -- :1 vt08` for the 8th VT. (This way, Xorg can even re-use VTs that already have a *getty* or another text-mode program running in them.)

See [Xorg(1)](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/Xorg.1.xhtml) for more about this.