# Multiple X displays per monitor

Tags: linux, display, x11-forwarding

I am developing software for a target system which has 3 displays, one per monitor: `localhost:0.0`, `localhost:0.1`, `localhost:0.2`

Though the target system has 3 monitors, my development system has only 2. To make the software work on a development system (which is lacking expected displays), all windows are put on `localhost:0.0` instead of their appropriate displays, so it can be tested on a dev system.

Sometimes I really *need* to test with 3 displays to guarantee that each display is showing what it should. If I'm on a windows system, I can run an X server in a mode which gives me 3 windows, each of which being a separate display: `0.0`, `0.1`, and `0.2`, then I use ssh with X-forwarding. Good. Is there any way I can do something similar on a Linux system?

The Linux system I use happens to be a red hat server that I get a remote desktop to from the windows computer.

Is there any way to run separate X displays on one monitor? Preferably having a separate window for each, but that is not strictly necessary.

In searching for an answer, I have found multiple things which may have been helpful if I understood them (or if I was even sure they were talking about the same thing).

Here's 1 solution I tried: there is a question here on superuser titled "Multiple X instances" which starts out with "I can run multiple X instances via `startx -- :1` ..." I tried it but got PAM authentication errors. Googling only yields a  bunch of people who only have that problem after su from root to another user, but I don't even have root access. Not sure if this is even what I want.

Another source I found: [How do I run more than one X display](https://superuser.com/questions/463045/how-do-i-run-more-than-one-x-display), which is another superuser question asking "I wish to run two X displays, one at alt + F7 and one at alt + F8. How do I do this?" which has an answer using `xinit` or `startx`.

The `startx`/`xinit` thing is the most promising lead I've come across. If this is what I need and I just am not doing it correctly, I can make a separate question about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Xnest** which supports up to 3 screens. Just run

```
Xnest -scrns 3 :1
```

and you get 3 windows each of which appears to an X11 client like a real screen on the one display.

> -scrns int
>   This  option  specifies  the  number of screens to create in the
>   nested server.  For each screen, Xnest will  create  a  separate
>   top-level window.  Each screen is referenced by the number after
>   the dot in the client display name specification.  For  example,
>   xterm  -display  :1.1 will open an xterm(1) client...

---

You don't need to be root to run `Xnest`, nor to download it if you have access to the rpm repository. Do

```
yumdownloader xorg-x11-server-Xnest
```

and you should get the rpm file which you can unpack with

```
rpm2cpio thefilewegot.rpm | cpio -civd ./usr/bin/Xnest
```

then you can run this `usr/bin/Xnest :1 ...`

Comment: That sounds like it would work great. Unfortunately, I get `Xnest: Command not found` and I do not have permissions to install anything. I'll put in a request to see if I can get that set up, then I'll try again if it gets done.

Comment: I just received word that Xnest will not be installed. This is unfortunate for me, but your answer still sounds like the best way to do what I wanted, assuming all I need to do is: run `Xnest -scrns 3 :1`, 3 new windows display representing :1.0, :1.1, :1.2, applications referencing :1.0 :1.1 :1.2 now appear in the 3 new windows.

Comment: Oh, and also assuming it does not give the same error that startx/xinit gave, which seemed (according to other websites) to want root.

Comment: @Aaron You might be able to download `Xnest` by yourself, not needing root, see my answer.